# How do I unlock the ARR beast tribe quests?

Tags: final-fantasy-14

I got to level 41 which seems to be the only requirement.
I am now level 47, my main quest is up to date (lvl 46) and I still don't see the quests for the beast tribes.

According to the wiki,

> Beast Tribe Quests don't unlock until you reach level 41 of the Main Scenario Quests, even if your character is over level 41. Once unlocked via the Main Scenario Quests the Beast Tribe Quests become dependent on character level and not Main Scenario Quest level.

Answer (score 8):

Each beast tribe questline starts with a new quest that becomes available in the city-state closest to where the beast tribe lives. Note that all beast tribe quests also require completion of the level 41 main scenario quest "In Pursuit of the Past" to unlock (if you have cleared Stone Vigil, you've done this quest). The specific starting quests are listed in the patch notes, but here's an easy reference:

**Sylphs**
Quest: Seeking Solace (requires level 42)
Location: New Gridania (X:9, Y:11)
NPC: Vorsaile Heuloix

**Amalj'aa**
Quest: Peace for Thanalan (requires level 43)
Location: Ul'dah - Steps of Nald (X:8, Y:8)
NPC: Swift

**Kobolds**
Quest: Highway Robbery (requires level 41)
Location: Limsa Lominsa Upper Decks (X:12 Y:12)
NPC: Trachraet

**Sahagin**
Quest: They Came from the Deep (requires level 44)
Location: Limsa Lominsa Upper Decks (X:13 Y:12)
NPC: R'ashaht Rhiki

**Ixal**
Quest: A Bad Bladder (technically requires level 1, but see prerequisites)
Location: New Gridania (X:9 Y:11)
NPC: Scarlet
*NOTE: You'll need a crafting job unlocked (of any level) in addition to your 41+ combat job to actually do any Ixal quests past this one.*